# Python: How to store a REQUEST for input in a variable?

Tags: python

I'm building a text game and need to store 2 things in a single variable: `a string, and a request for input`. Note that I *don't* mean to store the output of the request - I mean that if the variable is called, both the string and the *request itself* are printed, after which the user answers the request.

`raw_input("Do you do X or Y?")` therefore doesn't work for me, because I need to store the request before I deploy it.

**Some background about my approach:**

Everything's stored in a dictionary, where the keys are the user's current location and the values are possible choices:

```
dict = {location1: (location2, location3), location2: (location1, location4)...}
```

So, I'll `print location1`, which will simultaneously print the `string` that describes that location, and make a `request for input`. The input triggers the program to print the next appropriate location, and the program keeps on going.

I'm trying to work out a recursive function that does this.

For each location, the request for input is worded differently, which is why I don't just build the request into my recursive function.

Sidenote: if anyone has any other suggestions/different approaches I should use instead, please share those too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each location, the request for input is worded differently,

Simply create another dictionary for input request corresponding to each location. For ex:

```
requests_dict = {
    'location1': 'Please enter xxx: ',
    'location2': 'Do you do X or Y: ',    # and so on
}
```

Then use that dict to print the request.

```
user_input = raw_input(requests_dict['location2'])
```

Of course, you would like to make the last code based on some logic so that which one of that dicts is called, but I think you get the idea.

Update:

```
responses_dict = {}
user_input = raw_input(requests_dict['location2'])
responses_dict[user_input] = 'You are in %s' % user_input
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've written the extra dictionary, which gets me partway to where I want to be, but I'm still having trouble with the input request. I need to store the request for input inside a dictionary WITHOUT running it UNTIL my function gets to that entry in the dictionary. Any help there?

Comment: I am sure I will be able to help but I am a little confused about the question. Could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: What about creating one more dictionary and populating it dynamically. Please see update in my answer.

Comment: I just tried the code in your example, but the issue persists.

This hopefully describes the issue:

dictionary = {
 "dict1": "Dict entry 1",
 "dict2": "Dict entry 2",
 "dict3": "Dict entry 3",
 "dict4": raw_input("Dict entry 4: "),
 }

print dictionary["dict2"]

I want this to print the "dict2" value, but instead it prints the "dict4" value, I have to input something, and THEN it prints the "dict2" value. I want it to ignore "dict4" altogether. I have this problem whether the dictionary keys are just strings, or  are variables assigned elsewhere to strings.

Comment: See it does not print dict4 value, rather It has a *raw_input* in dict4 so it prints that prompt first. Because Of course that *raw_input* will be executed first and then the print. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Ah, so anytime the program processes a prompt, it'll run it and prompt the user, no matter where it's located. So I need to put the prompt itself (not the test that pops up when the prompt is run) in my function. I figured it out, tried it and it works! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: No Problem. I am glad it helped. Please select my answer as successful and upvote it :)

Comment: Haha, no problem. You will get a lot of privileges soon :)